# Change newline character .readline() seeks

Tags: python, input, readline

Is it possible to change the newline character the `.readline()` method looks for while reading lines?  I might have the need to read a stream from a file object that will be delimited in something other than newlines and it could be handy to get a chunk at a time.  `file` objects don't have a `readuntil` which I wouldn't have to create if I can use `readline`

**EDIT:**

---

I haven't yet tried it on a pipe other than `stdin`; but this seems to work.

```
class cfile(file):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        file.__init__(self, *args)

    def readuntil(self, char):
        buf = bytearray()
        while True:
            rchar = self.read(1)
            buf += rchar
            if rchar == char:
                return str(buf)
```

usage:

```
>>> import test
>>> tfile = test.cfile('/proc/self/fd/0', 'r')
>>> tfile.readuntil('0')
this line has no char zero
this one doesn't either,
this one does though, 0
"this line has no char zero\nthis one doesn't either,\nthis one does though, 0"
>>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Consider creating a generator using `file.read()` and yielding chunks delimited by given character.

**Edit:**

The sample you provided should work just fine. I would prefer to use a generator though:

```
def chunks(file, delim='\n'):
    buf = bytearray(), 
    while True:
        c = self.read(1)
        if c == '': return
        buf += c
        if c == delim: 
            yield str(buf)
            buf = bytearray()
```

Comment: I edited with a code sample of what I was thinking; subclassing the `file` object.

Comment: As currently written, this won't `yield` any trailing characters if the file doesn't end with the `delim` character. Perhaps it might be better to use `if c == '': return str(buf)`.