# Is there a way to read a file in a loop in python using a separator other than newline

Tags: python

I usually read files like this in Python:

```
f = open('filename.txt', 'r')
for x in f:
    doStuff(x)
f.close()
```

However, this splits the file by newlines.  I now have a file which has all of its info in one line (45,000 strings separated by commas).  While a file of this size is trivial to read in using something like

```
f = open('filename.txt', 'r')
doStuff(f.read())
f.close()
```

I am curious if for a much larger file which is all in one line it would be possible to achieve a similar iteration effect as in the first code snippet but with splitting by comma instead of newline, or by any other character?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: < http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284468/change-newline-character-readline-seeks >. Solution via subclassing the `file` object is given there.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to `close()` file objects once you're done with them.

Comment: @JoelCornett good point, edited my question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following function is a fairly straightforward way to do what you want:

```
def file_split(f, delim=',', bufsize=1024):
    prev = ''
    while True:
        s = f.read(bufsize)
        if not s:
            break
        split = s.split(delim)
        if len(split) > 1:
            yield prev + split[0]
            prev = split[-1]
            for x in split[1:-1]:
                yield x
        else:
            prev += s
    if prev:
        yield prev
```

You would use it like this:

```
for item in file_split(open('filename.txt')):
    doStuff(item)
```

This should be faster than the solution that EMS linked, and will save a lot of memory over reading the entire file at once for large files.

Comment: Does bufsize need to be as big as the item itself, or just the delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

Open the file using `open()`, then use the `file.read(x)` method to read (approximately) the next `x` bytes from the file. You could keep requesting blocks of 4096 characters until you hit end-of-file.

You will have to implement the splitting yourself - you can take inspiration from the `csv` module, but I don't believe you can use it directly because it wasn't designed to deal with extremely long lines.

Comment: You can do this with a file object on either Python 2 or 3. No reason to use `io`. Also, just to be clear, a file object is what you get when you call `open`. Don't use the actual `file` built-in.