# Shift + Return to insert linebreak in python

Tags: python, input, readline

I'm trying to get the behaviour of typical IM clients that use `Return` to send a text and `Shift + Return` to insert a linebreak. Is there a way to achieve that with minimal effort in Python, using e.g. [readline](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html) and `raw_input`?

Comment: Are you looking for platform dependent or independent answer?

Comment: Platform independent if possible, but *nix compatible should do as the application targets command line users anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I heard it can be accomplished also with the `readline`, in a way.

You can `import readline` and set in configuration your desired key (Shift+Enter) to a macro that put some special char to the end of the line and newline. Then you can call `raw_input` in a loop.

Like this:

```
import readline    
# I am using Ctrl+K to insert line break 
# (dont know what symbol is for shift+enter)
readline.parse_and_bind('C-k: "#\n"')
text = []
line = "#"
while line and line[-1]=='#':
  line = raw_input("> ")
  if line.endswith("#"):
    text.append(line[:-1])
  else:
    text.append(line)

# all lines are in "text" list variable
print "\n".join(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you'd be able to do that just using the `readline` module as it will not capture the individual keys pressed and rather just processes the character responses from your input driver.

You could do it with [PyHook](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=Main_Page) though and if the `Shift` key is pressed along with the `Enter` key to inject a new-line into your `readline` stream.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to maintain platform compatibility with *nix!

Answer (score 1):

I think that *with minimal effort* you can use [urwid](http://excess.org/urwid/) library for Python. Unfortunately, this does not satisfy your requirement to use readline/raw_input.

*Update:* Please see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284468/change-newline-character-readline-seeks?rq=1) for other solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import readline
# I am using Ctrl+x to insert line break 
# (dont know the symbols and bindings for meta-key or shift-key,  
# let alone 4 shift+enter)

def startup_hook():
    readline.insert_text('» ') # \033[32m»\033[0m

def prmpt():
try:
    readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
    readline.parse_and_bind('set editing-mode vi')
    readline.parse_and_bind('C-x: "\x16\n"') # \x16 is C-v which writes
    readline.set_startup_hook(startup_hook) # the \n without returning
except Exception as e:                      # thus no need 4 appending
    print (e)                              # '#' 2 write multilines
    return                # simply use ctrl-x or other some other bind
while True:             # instead of shift + enter
    try:
        line = raw_input()
        print '%s' % line
    except EOFError:
        print 'EOF signaled, exiting...'
        break

# It can probably be improved more to use meta+key or maybe even shift enter 
# Anyways sry 4 any errors I probably may have made.. first time answering
```